# If a datetime type object is non-nullable then does it mean it's mandatory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, soap, wsdl

If a client has given me a wsdl file which contain datetime as non-nullable then does it mean that its mandatory to pass datetime since it won't accept empty strings or null?

```
<s:element name="ANDTI" type="s:date" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" form="unqualified"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried using that XSD? The minOccurs attribute is 0, which means it's not required

Comment: Yes.  DateTime is often required as part of data inputs.

Comment: @Flydog57 it is becuase If I pass empty tag it throws error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nillable (not nullable) property on an element E means that it can be written as an empty element `<E xsi:nil="true"/>`, even though the type does not allow empty content. Being nillable does not make it optional, it only makes it emptiable.

Nillability is a feature of the XSD specification that 99.9% of users wisely ignore. I would recommend you do the same.